# Undefined variable: run_posts and Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, variables, warnings

```
 <div id="main_content"> 
<?php
 //error_reporting(0);
  include("includes/connect.php");

 $select_posts = " select * from posts ";

 $run = mysql_query($select_posts);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_posts)) {

$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$post_title = $row['post_title'];
$post_date = $row['post_date'];
$post_author = $row['post_author'];
$post_image = $row['post_image'];
$post_keywords = $row['post_keywords'];
$post_content = $row['post_content'];



?>

<h2> <?php echo $post_title; ?> </h2>

<?php } ?>
</div>
```

While creating CMS I am displaying the content on main page but getting usual error and warning

> Notice: Undefined variable: run_posts in C:\wamp\www\CMS\includes\main_content.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\CMS\includes\main_content.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

```
$run = mysql_query($select_posts);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_posts)) {
```

you are trying to fetch `$run_posts` instead of `$run` variable

Change the loop to `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch results from `$run_posts`, but your MySQL query is actually the `$run` variable. Look at the error message, that's exactly what it says.

Also, please do not use `mysql_*` anymore, switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_posts)) {
```

with

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
```